# how to store multiple mouse click coordinates python

Tags: python-3.x

so Ive been trying to find a way to store multiple click x and y's with no luck, Ive worked with pygame and opencv but I cannot find a way to store multiple x and y's without deleting the previous set.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print (pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

Comment: Do you mean for some list `clicks = []` something like `clicks.append((x,y))`?

Comment: Show the borken code. We can suggest a meaningful solution then, perhaps.

Comment: I put the code in the question, but for some reason it wont even work and its really making me mad because its simple, but the original question was how can i store multiple x, y's from mouse clicks and then re-access them afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Just append the `event.pos` or `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` to a list or [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) if the size should be limited.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

clicks = []
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            clicks.append(event.pos)
            print(clicks)

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```